# How to customize UITextField like this?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

another questions...

How can i make this textfield??

[image] [image]

With on the left a *FIXED placeholder* with a string and after it, an touchable zone, with *text* or *the blue rectangle* like screenshot.

I need to implement a view? Or there is a simple way to do it directly in textfield?

thanks again!
A

Comment: You can also try this method. It helps you. http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/01/04/uitextfield-a-complete-api-overview/

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I have the solution!!!

`UITextField` have a property named `leftView` and `rightView`!

Here's the code:

```
UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1, 1, 60, 25) ];
[lbl setText:@"Partenza:"];
[lbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:12]];
[lbl setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
[lbl setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
_txtFrom.leftView = lbl;
_txtFrom.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
_txtFrom.delegate = self;
```

and this is the output:
[image]

Comment: Just wanted to note that the real magic here is: _txtFrom.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;. In apple's documentation, you'll see that leftViewMode is defaulted to UITextFieldViewModeNever so without that line you'll probably just be scratching your head.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [TTMessageRecipientField](http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_message_recipient_field.php). On the Mac, this is achieved with an [NSTokenField](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTokenField_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSTokenField), but this isn't available in UIKit.