# How to add and delete multiple UILabel in TextField

Tags: iphone, ios

I am working UISearchView and I want to add multiple contacts of UILabel design in TextField of UISearchBar.

The approach I am doing is adding UILabel as subview of TextField with horizontal XPosition but I am getting problem to delete contacts as like we delete any text from UITextField after selecting of text pointer.

Can anybody share idea or reference How to Add/Delete multiple UILabel in UITextField.

Much more like this reference but it is adding only one UILabel and delete concept is not shared.

[How to customize UITextField like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769864/how-to-customize-uitextfield-like-this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term you're looking for is 'token'. Try using a 3rd party solution like [jstokenfield](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/jstokenfield) (just an example one, there are others on cocoacontrols / github).

Comment: Thanks Wain... Good Reference... :)